# Vim delete blank lines

Tags: vim, vi

What command can I run to remove blank lines in Vim?

Answer (score 1418, accepted):

```
:g/^$/d
```

`:g` will execute a command on lines which match a regex. The regex is 'blank line' and the command is `:d` (delete)

Comment: Thanks soulmerge. This is my favorite answer, since it actually explains what the :g command does.

Comment: This will delete all the empty lines(do not contain any white space characters..), but that may not be the unique requirement. Someone may still keep one of the empty line. `:%!cat -s` may be the choice..

Comment: :g/^\s*$/d
with a regex of 'any possible space char' in the line

Comment: @soulmerge what about adding range `1,$/^\s$/d` or  using tags `'a,'b/^\s$/d`? This does not work for me

Comment: @AlexanderCska should be `1,$g/^$/d`

Answer (score 216):

Found it, it's:

```
g/^\s*$/d
```

Source: [Power of *g* at vim wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g)

> Brief explanation of `:g`
>
> ```
> :[range]g/pattern/cmd
> ```
>
> This acts on the specified *[range]* (default whole file), by executing the Ex command *cmd* for each line matching *pattern* (an Ex command is one starting with a colon such as `:d` for delete). Before executing *cmd*, "`.`" is set to the current line.

Comment: Nice. But not exactly a blank line.

Comment: Ah, yes, this will match lines containing only whitespace characters. I'll accept soulmerge's answer.

Comment: that should match blank lines AND lines composed only of whitespaces... (* matches zero or multiple instances of \s...)?

Comment: I would argue pure whitespace IS EXACTLY a blank line, whereas no whitespace is really more of an empty line, don't ya think? ;)

Comment: Oxford says a blank is "a space left to be filled in a document". Interpret that as you may, but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Is there some man page where I can read about the used flags and the available ones for this command.

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSingh I know it's late but..yes. Try in vim: `:help :g` (at least if I understand you correctly). I'm not sure what you mean by flags as such since there aren't really any here I think but the command the answer here uses is `:g`.

Answer (score 58):

```
:v/./d
```

or

```
:g/^$/d
```

or

```
:%!cat -s
```

Comment: Neat trick with the :v/./d (easier to type) but then you need to do a :nohl after.

Comment: @ClaesMogren or just bounce on control-l

Comment: @zladuric according to http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Power_of_g it's reVerse global (so it does the command on everything that doesn't match)

Answer (score 46):

The following can be used to remove only multi blank lines (reduce them to a single blank line) and leaving single blank lines intact:

```
:g/^\_$\n\_^$/d
```

Comment: Could someone explain what the tokens mean? (So, how does it work?) Thanks.

Comment: `\_$` means the *end-of-line* that can be used inside a pattern (`$` can only be used at the end of the pattern.) Same is with `\_^` that means *the start of a line* and can be used anywhere inside the pattern. So, the pattern matches an empty line, a newline, and again an empty line. See [Vim regex help page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html).

Comment: Another way to do the same: `:g/^$/,/./-j`

Answer (score 15):

1. how to remove all the blanks lines

   ```
   :%s,\n\n,^M,g
   ```

   (do this multiple times util all the empty lines went gone)
2. how to remove all the blanks lines leaving SINGLE empty line

   ```
   :%s,\n\n\n,^M^M,g
   ```

   (do this multiple times)
3. how to remove all the blanks lines leaving TWO empty lines AT MAXIMUM,

   ```
   :%s,\n\n\n\n,^M^M^M,g
   ```

   (do this multiple times)

in order to input ^M, I have to control-Q and control-M in windows

Comment: You can also use `\r` in place of the `Ctrl-M`.

Answer (score 11):

This works for me

`:%s/^\s*$\n//gc`

Comment: I use something similar: `:%s/^\n//gc`

Comment: Good, the only that ask confirmation!

Comment: Clint's one actually works. i'm in neovim

Answer (score 8):

How about:

```
:g/^[ \t]*$/d
```

Answer (score 6):

Press <kbd>delete</kbd> key in insert mode to remove blank lines.

Answer (score 5):

work with perl in vim:

`:%!perl -pi -e s/^\s*$//g`

Comment: My perl may be a bit rust, but wouldn't `chomp` also do the job?

Answer (score 5):

This function only remove two or more blank lines, put the lines below in your vimrc, then use \d to call function

```
fun! DelBlank()
   let _s=@/
   let l = line(".")
   let c = col(".")
   :g/^\n\{2,}/d
   let @/=_s
   call cursor(l, c)
endfun
map <special> <leader>d :keepjumps call DelBlank()<cr>
```

Answer (score 5):

I tried a few of the answers on this page, but a lot of them didn't work for me. Maybe because I'm using Vim on Windows 7 (don't mock, just have pity on me :p)?

Here's the easiest one that I found that works on Vim in Windows 7:

```
:v/\S/d
```

Here's a longer answer on the Vim Wikia: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Remove_unwanted_empty_lines

Answer (score 4):

```
:g/^\s*$/d
^ begin of a line
\s* at least 0 spaces and as many as possible (greedy)
$ end of a line
```

paste

```
:command -range=% DBL :<line1>,<line2>g/^\s*$/d
```

in your .vimrc,then restart your vim.
if you use command :5,12DBL
it will delete all blank lines between 5th row and 12th row.
I think my answer is the best answer!

Comment: When posting answers, please add and explanation describing what you changed or added or how it works or something. Even though your answer may be the solution, it's likely that some people who read this don't understand what it means or how it works.
And please do it in english.

Comment: That doesn't really matter here. This question accepted an answer 5 years ago

Comment: I think soulmerge's answer :g/^$/d is not the best answer.and I edit to improve his answer with :g/^\s*$/d. but why I cannot watch my edit in "show all edits to this pose"?

Comment: My answer is better than his answer, and who rejected my answer and why my answer was rejected?

Answer (score 2):

If something has double linespaced your text then this command will remove the double spacing and merge pre-existing repeating blank lines into a single blank line. It uses a temporary delimiter of ^^^ at the start of a line so if this clashes with your content choose something else. Lines containing only whitespace are treated as blank.

```
%s/^\s*\n\n\+/^^^\r/g | g/^\s*$/d | %s/^^^^.*
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
:%s/^[^a-zA-Z0-9]$\n//ig
```

It basically deletes all the lines that don't have a number or letter.  Since all the items in my list had letters, it deleted all the blank lines.