# How do I tidy up an HTML file's indentation in VI?

Tags: html, vim, vi, indentation

How do I fix the indentation of his huge html files which was all messed up?

I tried the usual [`"gg=G` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/506075/how-do-i-fix-the-indentation-of-an-entire-file-in-vi), which is what I use to fix the indentation of code files.  However, it didn't seem to work right on HTML files.  It simply removed all the formatting.

I also tried setting `:filetype = xml`, to see if tricking it into thinking this was an XML file would help but it still didn't do it.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

With `filetype indent on` inside my `.vimrc`, Vim indents HTML files quite nicely.

Simple example with a `shiftwidth` of 2:

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
    text
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Copy paste the html of this questions page into a html file.  Open with VIM, type "set smartindent", then "gg=G" and it doesn't fix the indenting of the file.

Comment: It works for me. set ft=html<cr>set si<cr>gg=G<cr>. Formats this  page quite well.

Comment: Did a bit of fiddling, seems it's actually "filetype indent on" that does the magic.

Comment: +1 verified that "filetype indent on/off" switches the magic on or off.

Comment: Yes, after setting smart indent, filetype=html, and and filetype ident on it worked for me.

Comment: This is cool but it doesn't do exactly what I want. I want every new tag to be one level deeper but an <a> under a <li> is not indented. I'm going to see if I can get what I want from the alternative vim script. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: From http://www.chovy.com/web-development/fix-indentation-and-tabs-in-vim/ found that I needed to reload the file with :e after filetype indent on.

Comment: Note that in `vim 7.4` the default indentation settings will **fail** for this example, as `html`, `body`, and `p` are not indented by default. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19351416/446554).

Comment: vim default indentation is well. I like this. But when I install <a href="https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3818>matchtag</a> this nice feature is gone. I don't know why. I removed matchtag but not come the previous nice look. see this current indentation in my vim https://pasteboard.co/HeQ7RUS.png

Comment: Thanks @DonReba! I had already `set syn=html`, but didn't realise I also needed to `set ft=html` as well. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 218):

There's several things that all need to be in place. Just to summarize them all in one location:

Set the following option:

```
:filetype indent on
:set filetype=html           # abbrev -  :set ft=html
:set smartindent             # abbrev -  :set si
```

Then either move the cursor to the top of the file and indent to the end: `gg` `=G`
Or select the desired text to indent and hit <kbd>=</kbd> to indent it.

Comment: @tyrel, thanks, but for me is not working.. This is the file's content: http://pastebin.com/gagia8W2 . The file is called `home.html`. I don't have any problem to indent .php files. Here you have my .vimrc: http://pastebin.com/FAJ0MCA9

Comment: Is there a way I can set this in the .vimrc? I don't want to tell it everytime i open an HTML file that its an HTML file. Thanks a lot for gg,=,G shortcut. Really handy.

Comment: Note that in `vim 7.4` the default indentation settings will **fail** for this example, as `html`, `body`, and `p` are not indented by default. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19351416/446554).

Comment: `smartindent` isn't necessary. Also it's tuned for C and C++, I prefer to use more general `autoindent` instead.

Comment: It works great with vim7.4. @tylerl is there any way to make this configuration permanent for html files in 7.4?

Comment: `:set smartindent` worked well for me in combination with `1G` `v` `G` `$` `=` (go to first line, set visual mode, go to last line, go to end of last line, smart indent).  this selects all the text then indents.

Comment: Major caveat: if you run these commands in the vim command line, you need to re-open the file with `:e`. This is not necessary if putting them into `~/.vimrc`

Comment: A tip for people who like `gg=G`, try `gg=G\`\``, then try `:set nnoremap <leader>ii gg=G\`\`` .  That way, you just press `\ii` and you re-indent your whole file and go back to precisely where you were (you can also use this, for example, with clang-format for c++... `:set equalprg=clang-format` ... etc...)

Answer (score 77):

The main problem using the smart indentation is that if the XML (or HTML) sits on one line as it may end up coming back from a curl request then `gg=G` won't do the trick. Instead I have just experienced a good indentation using tidy directly called from VI:

```
:!tidy -mi -xml -wrap 0 %
```

This basically tells VI to call tidy to cleanup an XML file not wrapping the lines to make them fit on the default 68 characters wide lines. I processed a large 29MB XML file and it took 5 or 6 seconds. I guess for an HTML file the command should therefore be:

```
:!tidy -mi -html -wrap 0 %
```

As mentioned in comments, `tidy` is a basic tool which you could find on many base Linux / MacOS systems. Here is the projet's page in case you wish you had it but don't: [HTML Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org).

Comment: I don't believe html is needed, as it defaults to html

Comment: Agreed with you @Isieber. However, I guess it makes it easier to understand the logic and might even be considered good practice by some people.

Comment: FYI, tidy chokes if the HTML includes SVG (e.g., charts, etc.).

Comment: Yes, if the html code is on one line, the vim indent command won't work!

Comment: What is tidy other than a word in a dictionary? This is not a complete answer without linking to the project.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky `tidy` ships with the standard Unix-like OSs. I successfully tried this answer on my Mac without ever having heard of `tidy`.

Comment: @RamanShah not without `brew install tidy-html5` you didn't. And that's the point of my comment. Not to say "please do my Googling for me". But to say, this answer needs to be better. And it's still true. Even if I was able to start using Tidy because of this answer.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky which system do you use?
```
$ tidy --version
HTML Tidy for Mac OS X released on 31 October 2006 - Apple Inc. build 15.18.1
```

Comment: So I defintely used `tidy` without a Homebrew installation. It's quite possible that typical Linux distros don't come with Tidy, which would be useful info for the present discussion.

Comment: Was not installed in my Ubuntu 19

Comment: I had to surround % with single quotes '%' otherwise the shell was interpreting some of the html.

Answer (score 49):

As tylerl explains above, set the following:

```
:filetype indent on
:set filetype=html
:set smartindent
```

However, note that in vim 7.4 the HTML tags `html`, `head`, `body`, and some others are **not** indented by default. This makes sense, as nearly all content in an HTML file falls under those tags. If you really want to, you can get those tags to be indented like so:

```
:let g:html_indent_inctags = "html,body,head,tbody"
```

See "[HTML indenting not working in compiled Vim 7.4, any ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323607/html-indenting-not-working-in-compiled-vim-7-4-any-ideas)" and "[alternative html indent script](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2075)" for more information.

Answer (score 16):

None of the answers worked for me because all my HTML was in a single line.

Basically you need first to break each line with the following command that substitutes `><` with the same characters but with a line break in the middle.

```
:%s/></>\r</g
```

Then the command

```
gg=G
```

will indent the file.

Comment: :%s/>\s*</>\r</g

Answer (score 13):

This is my solution that works nicely for opening "ugly" HTML in a nicely spaced way:

```
vim fileIn.html -c "set sw=2 | %s/>/>\r/ | execute 'normal gg=G' | set nohlsearch | g/^\\s*\$/d"
```

- The `sw` command is because my default is 4, which is too high for HTML.
- The next part adds a newline (Vim thinks it's a carriage return, sigh) after each element (`>`).
- Then re-indent the entire file with `=`.
- Then unhighlight `>` (since I have `set hlsearch` in my vimrc).
- Then remove all empty/whitespace-only lines (see "[Vim delete blank lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706076/vim-delete-blank-lines)" for more, also this is double-escaped because it's in the shell).

You can even add `| wq! fileOut.html` to the end if you don't want to enter Vim at all, but just clean up the file.

Comment: Neat solution! I modified it to `:%s/>\s*/>\r/g` (added a `g` for global replace, and `\s*` to strip out trailing whitespace). I also added `:%s/</\r</g` to add a newline before the open bracket. Otherwise tags like `<td>foo</td>` would be split like `<td>` and `foo</td>`.

Comment: Fair point, I have global replace turned on by default which is why it's not in my solution.

Answer (score 8):

I use this script:
https://github.com/maksimr/vim-jsbeautify

In the above link you have all the info:

1. Install
2. Configure (copy from the first example)
3. Run `:call HtmlBeautify()`

Does the job beautifully!

Comment: haha, why would you want to use node + js to clean up html in vim, which has had this capability builtin for longer than node even exists... boggles my mind..

Answer (score 5):

Here's a heavy-weight solution that gets you indenting, plus all the HTML pretty-printing you don't necessarily want to care about while you're editing.

First, download [Tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/#binaries). Make sure you add the binary to your path, so you can call it from any location.

Next, create a config file describing your favorite HTML flavor. Documentation is not great for Tidy, but here's an [overview](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/), and a list of [all the options](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html). Here's my config file:

```
bare: yes
break-before-br: no
clean: yes
drop-proprietary-attributes: yes
fix-uri: yes
indent-spaces: 4
indent: yes
logical-emphasis: yes
markup: yes
output-xhtml: yes
quiet: yes
quote-marks: yes
replace-color: yes
tab-size: 4
uppercase-tags: no
vertical-space: yes
word-2000: yes
wrap: 0
```

Save this as `tidyrc_html.txt` in your `ftplugin` folder (under vimfiles).

One more file: add the following line to (or create) `html.vim`, also in `ftplugin`:

```
map <leader>tidy :%! tidy -config ~/vimfiles/ftplugin/tidyrc_html.txt <CR>
```

To use it, just open an HTML file, and type `/tidy`. (That `/` is the `<leader>` key.)

There you go! Not a quick solution, by any means, but now you're a bit better equipped for editing those huge, messed-up HTML files.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using the HTML indentation script on the Vim site?

- http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2075

Comment: +1, I didn't see that.  It would be nice if I didn't need to run a script but it looks like this might be the only way.

Comment: This script is deprecated now, and a newer version comes with vim (e.g. `/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/html.vim`). "2014 Jul 04: Vim 7.4.356 or later includes a descendant of this script (the official script is now maintained by Bram and includes massive changes)"

Answer (score 3):

You can integrate both [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) and [html-beautify](https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify) automatically by installing the plugin [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat).
After that, you can execute whichever formatter is installed with a single keystroke.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried the usual "gg=G" command, which is what I use to fix the indentation of code files. However, it didn't seem to work right on HTML files. It simply removed all the formatting.

If vim's autoformat/indent `gg=G` seems to be "broken" (such as left indenting every line), most likely the indent plugin is not enabled/loaded. It should really give an error message instead of just doing bad indenting, otherwise users just think the autoformat/indenting feature is awful, when it actually is pretty good.

To check if the indent plugin is enabled/loaded, run `:scriptnames`. See if `.../indent/html.vim` is in the list. If not, then that means the plugin is not loaded. In that case, add this line to `~/.vimrc`:

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

Now if you open the file and run `:scriptnames`, you should see `.../indent/html.vim`. Then run `gg=G`, which should do the correct autoformat/indent now. (Although it won't add newlines, so if all the html code is on a single line, it won't be indented).

Note: if you are running `:filetype plugin indent on` on the vim command line instead of `~/.vimrc`, you must re-open the file `:e`.

Also, you don't need to worry about `autoindent` and `smartindent` settings, they are not relevant for this.

Answer (score 0):

Tagging onto wisbucky's answer, here were my steps to diagnose and fix the basic use of `gg=G` for indenting xml:

Detecting that there's a problem:

```
gg=G
(says 115 lines indented but actually all lines are still at left edge)

:se indentexpr?
indentexpr=

:scriptnames
(look for one ending in /indent/xml.vim but it's not there)
(look in system folder to make sure /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent/xml.vim exists --- it does)
```

Fixing the problem:

```
:se ft?
filetype=xml

:filetype
filetype detection:ON  plugin:OFF  indent:OFF

:filetype indent on
:filetype
filetype detection:ON  plugin:OFF  indent:ON

:e
:se indentexpr?
indentexpr=XmlIndentGet(v:lnum, 1)

gg=G
```

The `:se indentexpr?` sanity check is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11660992/115246