# Automatically indent code with broken indentation in vim

Tags: vim, indentation

I am working with a CMS where the code's indentation is a mess. Is it possible to fix it automatically with vim, running some command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally you can use the `=` operation to indent.

See `:help =`

(You'll also need to have `filetype indent on` in your vimrc to enable different indentation rules for each type of file you'll edit)

`gg=G` will reindent a whole file. (gg move to beginning of the file, = will reindent every line under motion, G goes to the end of the file)

By default, Vim support well C and C like language. See `:help C-indenting` for options. You'll probably need to adjust these options before reformating your files. You'll have to define `set cindent` in your .vimrc if you want to use the "smart" indentations that is controlled by `cinoptions`.

See `:help indent-expression`for other languages.

In addition, you'll probably will have to fiddle with`shiftwidth`, `expandtab` and `tabstop` options if you want to use whitespaces or tab to indent.

For example, if you to replace all tab by 4 spaces, you 'll have to use:

```
set shiftwidth=4             " used by >>, << and tab.  
set tabstop=4                " number of space characters used when displaying TAB  
set expandtab                " replace TAB by spaces
```

Comment: Thank you! I had these options enabled and just tried that with simple html files - it works fine. However if the file is a mess like smarty view file that I work with now looks like I need to deep into the indent-expression theory.. )

Answer (score 1):

I usually do this with `ggVG=`. `gg` = go to file start, `V` = mark lines, `G` = go to file end, `=` = indent.

Maybe it is not the fewest keystrokes to do this, but I think it's easy to remember.

Comment: And what does = exactly do? The result isn't completely the one I expected. I am trying to indent the view file, and all html in it is now clipped to the left, but not indented. This could help a bit but still requires manual indentation after.

Comment: If you want to reformat html, see the answer to that question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815548/how-do-i-tidy-up-an-html-files-indentation-in-vi/815560#815560