# How to get Vim auto indentation to keep indents on new lines

Tags: vim, notepad++, auto-indent

I have `set autoindent` in my .vimrc

Say I'm on an indented line in Vim in insert mode. If I make a bunch of new lines by pressing enter, it'll keep my cursor indented. However, lines between my current line and the original line lose their indents. This doesn't happen with Notepad++

`|` indicates the indent on the empty lines.

Vim:

```
function f()
{
    var x;
|
|
|
    |//cursor
```

Notepad++:

```
function f()
{
    var x;
    |
    |
    |
    |//cursor
```

How do I get Vim to behave like Notepad++?

Comment: Do you really want to have all those trailing white spaces?

Comment: possible duplicate of [stopping vim from removing indentation on empty lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413036/stopping-vim-from-removing-indentation-on-empty-lines)

Answer (score 1):

Try this and let me know if it fixes your problem.

** In normal mode **

```
:set smartindent
```

** Or in your .vimrc file add this **

```
set smartindent
```

Comment: Nope. I didn't notice any difference.

Comment: Linny, what version vim are you using?

Comment: Interesting...I've got 7.3, tested your scenario, and smartindent worked for me. The only other command that might work is cindent.
This guy seems to be having similar issues with that version...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323607/html-indenting-not-working-in-compiled-vim-7-4-any-ideas

Answer (score 0):

I have these settings in my .vimrc to auto indent:

```
" Auto indent.
filetype indent on
filetype plugin indent on
set smartindent
autocmd BufRead,BufWritePre *.py normal gg=G
set expandtab
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set autoindent
```

Please note that the "*.py" in "autocmd..." is for python file, you can change it to .sh or .cpp that fit you best.