# Vim 7.4 applies no indenting to HTML files

Tags: html, ubuntu, vim

I'm trying to get Vim (version 7.4), running on Ubuntu (14.04 LTS), to apply automatic indentation to HTML files. I know from the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323607/html-indenting-not-working-in-compiled-vim-7-4-any-ideas) that several tags you'd expect to cause indentation are not indented by default in Vim 7.4, and I know that's not the problem. Even the `<div>` tag, which should cause indentation in the default configuration, does not result in any indentation for me. If I type in the minimal example from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/392573/how-do-i-get-vim-to-indent-all-html-tags), I get the following:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test page</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that the `<p>` is not indented inside the `<div>`. Even if I save the file and do `gg=G`, Vim displays `12 lines indented` but the `<p>` remains unindented.

My .vimrc has the required lines

```
set autoindent
filetype indent plugin on
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
```

If I do `:set filetype?` while editing the example HTML file, I get `filetype=html` so the filetype is getting detected properly, and `/usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/html.vim` exists. Furthermore, syntax highlighting is correct for HTML, so at least some filetype-specific files are getting loaded correctly.

Does anyone know why the indenting rules aren't being applied to HTML files?

Comment: Everything is explained in `:help ft-html-indent`.

Comment: Uh, no it isn't. That help section explains how to use `g:html_indent_inctags` to add additional tags that should be indented, but my problem is that even the default tags that should be indented out-of-the-box (such as `<div>`) are not getting indented.

Comment: Uh, yes it is. `g:html_indent_inctags` is empty by default, you need to add tags to it: `g:html_indent_inctags='html,body,head,...'`.

Comment: That variable represents *additional* tags to indent beyond the default ones, as documented here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19330009/1500563. Either way, though, if I `:let g:html_indent_inctacs='div'` and re-apply indenting with `=`, the `<p>` inside the `<div>` is still not indented at all.