# vim, right way to indent css and js inside html

Tags: javascript, html, css, vim

Couldn't find proper solution in old questions, so

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <style type="text/css">
body, input{
    background-color:red;
}
        </style>
        <script>
function test() {
    return false
}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

everything except code inside `<style>` and `<script>` tags indented ok, how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I tidy up an HTML file's indentation in VI?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815548/how-do-i-tidy-up-an-html-files-indentation-in-vi)

Comment: @bozzmob, it's about pure html file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [othree/html5.vim](https://github.com/othree/html5.vim) plugin which [supports](https://github.com/othree/html5.vim/blob/76da614eaf9ec46c1cf67ddc22b85bc7f40e48af/indent/html.vim#L288) css/javascript inside html. It works although this isn't probably the simplest solution.

Your code is indented like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">
      body, input{
        background-color:red;
      }
    </style>
    <script>
      function test() {
        return false
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7):

As it turns out: That this has been done on purpose! Even my current Vim 8.1 installation contains an `indent/html.vim`-file which has such zero-indentation as its default setting.

That is however configurable via `vimrc` with:

```
let g:html_indent_script1 = "inc" 
let g:html_indent_style1 = "inc"
```

...and *-shame on us-* is also mentioned in `:help html-indent`

Comment: This answer needs to be at the top of the internet. I spent more than an hour trying to figure out how to do this thing that *must be simple*. Turns out it is simple!

Comment: Wait no...It works for style tags, but it indents javascript incorrectly unless I put all of the code inside the tags within {}. Do you not see this?

Comment: But it should. I found a bug report and made a change request here: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3205