# How can I delete empty lines in motion in Vim

Tags: vim

I know how to [delete blank lines with commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706076/vim-delete-blank-lines).

We may visually select the text block first, and then run commands like 
[`s/^$/d`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706076/vim-delete-blank-lines) to delete all blank lines or [`%s/^\(\s*\n\)\+/\r`](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/How-to-remove-empty-lines-except-of-one-td5709395.html) to keep only one blank lines.

Can I perform the above using motion, so that I can just press some keys to perform the "delete-motion" without having to enter command-line mode?

Comment: Well, you can make a key mapping to that ex-command.

Comment: `d/^.` will delete from here until the next non-blank line, or if you've already done that search before, then simply `dn`, but "here" needs to be a sensible value.  Will that do?

Comment: @sh1, Thank you! Then for deleting backwards `d/.$`! Probably I would have not asked this question if I knew `d/^.`. :)

Comment: @Hongying, unfortunately the reverse pattern seems to eat the last character of the non-empty line.  I thought it would be `d?^\@!$`, but no such luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a new operator for this is a good idea, but it can be tough to get right.

The [***operator-user***](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2692) plugin makes that task easy.

Once you have installed *operator-user*, all you need to do is add two lines to your vimrc, one to define the operator, and one to define your personal mapping to it:

```
call operator#user#define_ex_command('delete-blanks', 'g/^$/d')
map _ <Plug>(operator-delete-blanks)
```

This creates a new operator `_`. Change it to whatever you like best.

Now you can do `_3}` or `_G` or `_23k` to delete the blank lines contained in the motion. Text objects `_a}`, doubling of the operator `4__`, and Visual mode `V7j_` are all also supported, as befits a proper operator.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `operatorfunc`. For example:

Define a function like this in your .vimrc:

```
function! DeleteEmptyLines(type)
    if a:type == 'line'
        silent execute ".,'\"g/^$/d"
    endif
endfunction
```

And a mapping:

```
nnoremap <silent> ,d :set operatorfunc=DeleteEmptyLines<CR>m"g@
```

`,d` performs now just like an operator and accepts a (line-based) motion. You can, for example, insert `,d5j` or `,dG` in normal mode to delete empty lines in the next 5 lines or to the end of file.

You can find more information on how to extend this functionality here:
http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/33.html
and of course:`:h operatorfunc` and `:h map-operator`.

From `:h map-operator`:

"An operator is used before a {motion} command.  To define your own operator
you must create mapping that first sets the `operatorfunc` option and then
invoke the `g@` operator.  After the user types the {motion} command the
specified function will be called."

Comment: Thanks! It seems promising! (`,dG` works as we expect, but neither `,d` nor `,d5j` works. They just work like `d` and `d5j`.)

Comment: I probably had my jumplist mixed up when I was testing it. It seems like `10j` does not count as a "jump" and therefore can't be accessed by `'[` and `']`. You should be able to do it by setting a mark before executing `g@` and then using this mark in the range to the global command => see my updated post.

Comment: Ok, somehow it seems to work fine if the direction is upwards. Downwards movement doesn't work however. Maybe somebody else could help here. May this be a bug in vim?

Answer (score 1):

well, using motions I don't think you can only delete blank lines.

But you can do it using a mapping:

```
:nmap <Leader>db :g/^$/d<CR>
```

The motions help you move one word, one paragraph away... And before the motion you use an operator (`d`, `c`...).

So what you'd want is to create a new operator that deletes blank lines within the given motion (or selection). What I gave you is close to that, but you'd have to invent a new operator (and I don't think there's many unbound keys left).

Other vimmers may correct me, but I think the easiest way to create such operators would be to define a map for each motion and bind it to a function.

Comment: How does Vim let motion and build in commands work together, e.g., `d}`? Couldn't we define some key strokes like that?

Answer (score -1):

There isn't a motion that can combine with a delete such that it only deletes blank lines. A motion denotes all the text between the initial and final position, without any gaps. That includes motions which search using regular expressions.