# Vim / Sed: Delete Only Single Blank Lines

Tags: vim, sed

How can you delete *only* single blank lines in sed/vim?

Several questions already address [Deleting Blank Lines in ViM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/706076/vim-delete-blank-lines), however I want to leave multiple blank lines intact (or as single blank lines), so that:

```
this

kind

of


thing
```

Becomes

```
this
kind
of 

thing
```

Comment: Actually, some of the answers at the post you link to address some of what you want. I bet you could tweak [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10403658/26702) for example.

Comment: @Telemachus saw that and was playing with it for a while before asking but while it's clear enough how to define the "n_blank>=2/3/4/5", it's not clear how to go about inverting this limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one is working well:

```
:%s/^\n\(^\n\)*/\1/
```

Comment: Brill, does what it says on the tin; should have thought of "match and put it back"... Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be to use :g.  It isn't any faster or better than the :%s solution, but it feels like it is easier to read (at least for me):

```
:g /^$/ d
```

Comment: Oops, never mind.  I didn't see that you wanted to keep the multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^\n*$/!b;N;//!D' file
```

This will delete an empty line between two non-empty lines and other empty lines as is, or:

```
sed '/^\n*$/!b;N;//!D;:a;z;N;//ba' file
```

As above but this also squeezes multiple empty lines to a single empty line.